# Laravel combining two jquery functions in one button to insert products into Cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

This is very complex problem for me, I have table of products and table for related products, I'm able to insert products and related products but I have to click on two buttons which is not a logical way, I have modal dialogue shows the product and checkboxes for related products, I want to combine the two ajax in one button, I tried many ways but not worked

ajax for related product

```
    $(function(){
    $('.addrelated').on("click", function (){
    var insert=[];

    $('.get_value').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {

    insert.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    }
    });

    insert=insert.toString();
    $.ajax({
    url:"add-to-cart",
    method:"get",
    data:{insert:insert},
    success:function(data){

    }
    });
    });
    });
```

ajax for main product

```
    $(function(){ 
    $('.add_to_cart').on("click", function () { 

    var id = ($("#item_id").val());

    $quantity=$('#quantity').text();

    $.ajax({ 
      url: 'cart/' + id+'/edit', 
      data: {'quantity':$quantity},
    type: "get", 
    success: function (data) 
    { 

    $('#myModal').modal('hide'); 


    $('#cart_product').html(data); 

    } 

    }); }); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the first ajax use this

```
    $.ajax({
  url:"add-to-cart",
   method:"get",
   data:{insert:insert},
 success:function(data){

}
}).always(function () {// here the function for the main product
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me but it looks like you can do this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.addboth').on("click", function (){
    // related product code starts here
    var insert=[];

    $('.get_value').each(function(){
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        insert.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
      }
    });

    insert=insert.toString();
    $.ajax({
      url:"add-to-cart",
      method:"get",
      data:{insert:insert},
      success:function(data){
      }
    });

    // main product code starts here
    var id = ($("#item_id").val());

    $quantity=$('#quantity').text();

    $.ajax({ 
      url: 'cart/' + id+'/edit', 
      data: {'quantity':$quantity},
      type: "get", 
      success: function (data) { 
        $('#myModal').modal('hide'); 


        $('#cart_product').html(data); 

      } 
    });
});
```